# Turbo Stream link_to strips out custom attributes in GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-get, turbolinks, hotwire-rails, hotwire

I'm using Rails 7. I wanted to create a link using link_to that inserts some custom form fields for a many-to-many relation into a form via a hotwired frame elsewhere on the page. In order to customize the form fields generated (setting defaults etc) I need to include some custom parameters in the request:

```
<%= link_to "Add crew to ship",
      new_crew_path(ship_id: ship.id),
      data: { turbo_method: :get,
              turbo_stream: true } %>
```

The HTML looks correct, but when clicking the link, the parameter seems to have been stripped away:

```
<a data-turbo-method="get" data-turbo-stream="true" href="/crews/new?ship_id=1">Add crew to ship</a>
...
Started GET "/crews/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-24 13:49:23 +0100
Processing by CrewsController#new as TURBO_STREAM
```

If I remove the data map defining `turbo_stream: true` so it becomes a regular request, it works fine:

```
<%= link_to "Add crew to ship",
      new_crew_path(ship_id: ship.id) %> 

Started GET "/crews/new?ship_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-24 13:53:26 +0100
Processing by CrewsController#new as HTML
Incoming parameters: {"ship_id"=>"1"}
```

Same for changing it to a POST request, so it goes to the #create action of the controller instead, that also works:

```
<%= link_to "Add crew to ship",
            crews_path(ship_id: ship.id),
            data: { turbo_method: :post,
                    turbo_stream: true }  %>

Started POST "/crews?ship_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-24 13:58:01 +0100
Processing by CrewsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
Incoming parameters: {"ship_id"=>"1"}
```

So I have workarounds. Nevertheless, out of curiousity, is there some way to make GET turbo requests submit the custom params? From a REST perspective it feels like the most correct request method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `turbo_method: :get` the link is treated as a form and *GET* forms overwrite url query params with form params. As a test:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

document.addEventListener("turbo:before-fetch-request", (event) => {
  console.log(event.target)
})
// you get this "fake" form in the console, that Turbo submits instead of a link:
// <form data-turbo="true" action="http://localhost:3000/?ship_id=1" hidden="" method="get" data-turbo-stream=""></form>
```

If you just change the link to this:

```rb
<%= link_to "Add crew to ship",
  new_crew_path(ship_id: ship.id),
  data: { turbo_stream: true } %>
```

Now it's a regular *GET* turbo stream link, and query params should stay untouched.

---

For some extra details:
*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/647*

> it's worth emphasizing that declaring `[data-turbo-method="get"]` on an
> `<a>` element is redundant, and **should be avoided**

*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/821*

Comment: Ah, the one combination I apparently didn't try. Thank you.

Comment: your last statement feels like those kind of details are quite 'unstable', if i may. rails 7.0.7, hotwired/rails 7.2.4.could not make it work with data: { turbo_stream: true } only, had to specify also the turbo_method: :get

Comment: @Ben I think this issue has been fixed, you might want to update to turbo v7.3.0. a link sends a GET request already,  `data-turbo-method="get"` doesn't change that, it's not unstable, just unnecessary. if you add `turbo_method: :get` as well then you're going back to what the issue in the question was.